# 40% Channel Utilization on 1Mb Satellite

Tags: wireless, communication, simulation, bit-rate, propagation

Using the Slide Window technique, consider a satellite channel with:

- 500 byte frames sends
- 270 ms delay on send and receive
- 1 Mbps rate
- communication protocol is Sliding-windows
  Ignore the length of ACK messages.

#### How many bits are needed for numbering the Frames to achieve 40% Chanel utilization?

My professor calculated it to be 5 bits.
But I think 6 bits is correct.
Can anyone could help me which of these answer is true?

*EDIT: he used : U = w / (1+2a) formula.*

First Answer:
`1/(1+2a) = 1 / 136   --->  W/136 >= 4/10 ---> W>= 54/4  ----> 6 bit.`

Second Answer (the way one person solved it):
[image]

I search on the net and found something similar:

[http://staffhome.ecm.uwa.edu.au/~00014742/teach/ind426/handouts/tutorials/solutions/tute3.pdf](http://staffhome.ecm.uwa.edu.au/%7E00014742/teach/ind426/handouts/tutorials/solutions/tute3.pdf)

in problem 1-b. but i couldn't infer any new things for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see, it takes 500 bytes * 8 bits/byte / 1E6 bits/second = 4 ms to send a frame.

If the round-trip delay is 270 + 270 = 540 ms, then you'll have 540 / 4 = 135 frames "in flight" before the first one is acknowledged.

You need enough bits in the frame number to count at least this high, so you need 8 bits.

It looks to me like you're both wrong.

**EDIT:** Sorry, that was for 100% utilization. If you only need 40% utilization, then you only need enough frames to fill 40% of the round-trip delay, which would be 540 ms * 40% = 216 ms, which would then be 216 ms / 4 ms = 54 frames. You'll need 6 bits to count this many frames.

Comment: Dear @Dave, thanks from your idea, but with sliding window i thing 5 or 6 is correct. i edit a minor my question.

Comment: Dear @Dave, why my teacher is wrong?

Comment: I don't know for sure, since none of the terms used in the equations are defined, but the first step looks suspect to me. It's clear that \$T_F\$ represents the frame time, but what does \$T_P\$ (which is assumed to be equal to 135 ms) represent, and where does this value come from?

Comment: Dear @Dave, i think 270 / 2 and he maybe though the delay in one way? am i right? what about he ?

Comment: Dear @Davem what is the role of communication protocol is Sliding-windows?

Comment: The "sliding window" refers to the buffer of frames that the transmit side must hold onto between the time that they're transmittted and the time that they're acknowledged. If the acknowledgement fails for any particular frame, then it can be retransmitted from the buffer. If the acknowledgement is good, then the frame is simply discarded from the buffer, making room for new frames.